# Data is present in clipboard, but I can't get it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard, paste, nightwatch.js

I know this question was asked before, I read almost everything. The problem I have is, that value that I copied is available when pressing `ctrl+v`, but not when trying `window.getSelection.getData()`.

```
const copyToClipboard = (value) => {
    const temp = document.createElement('input');
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(temp);
    temp.value = value;
    temp.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    body.removeChild(temp);
};
```

Now, when I try `ctrl+v`, the pasted value is correct. When I try to use `window.getSelection.getData()`, there is no data.

But when I comment out the last line (`body.removeChild(temp)`), then both `ctrl+v` and `window.getSelection.getData()` works correctly. But I have an element in the dom.

Is there a way to get this value in code? I need this for tests in `Nightwatch`.

Comment: Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection. window.getSelection() has nothing to do with clipboard.